# Empty space between tab and content

Tags: css, tabs, transform, slide, translate

I want to display the contents of each tab. But there is an empty space.

There is no free space in the first tab but it exists in other tabs. I want to remove this gap

How to fix this problem? (Please do not suggest any Java Script code.)

The following figure shows this problem

[There is an empty space between the tab and the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlPRt.jpg)

```css
.tab-caption:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

.tab-caption:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: #AAFFAA;
}

.tab-caption:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #AAAAFF;
}

.tab-content:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

.tab-content:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: #AAFFAA;
}

.tab-content:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #AAAAFF;
}

.tab-status {
    display: none;
}

    .tab-status ~ .tab-caption-container {
        display: flex;
    }

        .tab-status ~ .tab-caption-container > .tab-caption {
            opacity: 0.4;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    .tab-status:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .tab-caption-container > .tab-caption:nth-of-type(1) {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .tab-status:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .tab-caption-container > .tab-caption:nth-of-type(2) {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .tab-status:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .tab-caption-container > .tab-caption:nth-of-type(3) {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .tab-status ~ .tab-content-container > .tab-content {
        width: 100%;
        transform: translate(-100%);
        transition: all 1s;
    }

    .tab-status:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .tab-content-container > .tab-content:nth-of-type(1),
    .tab-status:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .tab-content-container > .tab-content:nth-of-type(2),
    .tab-status:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .tab-content-container > .tab-content:nth-of-type(3) {
        transition: all 1s;
        transform: translate(0%);
        transition-delay: 1s;
    }

.tab-content-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<input class="tab-status" id="tabSwitch01" type="radio" name="tab" checked="checked">
    <input class="tab-status" id="tabSwitch02" type="radio" name="tab">
    <input class="tab-status" id="tabSwitch03" type="radio" name="tab">
    <div class="tab-caption-container">
        <label class="tab-caption" for="tabSwitch01">tab1</label>
        <label class="tab-caption" for="tabSwitch02">tab2</label>
        <label class="tab-caption" for="tabSwitch03">tab3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content-container">
        <div class="tab-content">tab1-data<br></div>
        <div class="tab-content">tab2-data<br>tab2-data<br></div>
        <div class="tab-content">tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the CSS for `.tab-content` such that the height is animated also. I also removed the float for `.tab-content-container` since it didn't have any purpose.

```css
.tab-caption:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

.tab-caption:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #AAFFAA;
}

.tab-caption:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
}

.tab-content:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

.tab-content:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #AAFFAA;
}

.tab-content:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
}

.tab-status {
  display: none;
}

.tab-status~.tab-caption-container {
  display: flex;
}

.tab-status~.tab-caption-container>.tab-caption {
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-status:nth-of-type(1):checked~.tab-caption-container>.tab-caption:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}

.tab-status:nth-of-type(2):checked~.tab-caption-container>.tab-caption:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}

.tab-status:nth-of-type(3):checked~.tab-caption-container>.tab-caption:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}

.tab-status~.tab-content-container>.tab-content {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%);
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 0;
}

.tab-status:nth-of-type(1):checked~.tab-content-container>.tab-content:nth-of-type(1),
.tab-status:nth-of-type(2):checked~.tab-content-container>.tab-content:nth-of-type(2),
.tab-status:nth-of-type(3):checked~.tab-content-container>.tab-content:nth-of-type(3) {
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: translate(0%);
  transition-delay: 1s;
  height: 100%;
}

.tab-content-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input class="tab-status" id="tabSwitch01" type="radio" name="tab" checked="checked">
<input class="tab-status" id="tabSwitch02" type="radio" name="tab">
<input class="tab-status" id="tabSwitch03" type="radio" name="tab">
<div class="tab-caption-container">
  <label class="tab-caption" for="tabSwitch01">tab1</label>
  <label class="tab-caption" for="tabSwitch02">tab2</label>
  <label class="tab-caption" for="tabSwitch03">tab3</label>
</div>
<div class="tab-content-container">
  <div class="tab-content">tab1-data<br></div>
  <div class="tab-content">tab2-data<br>tab2-data<br></div>
  <div class="tab-content">tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br>tab3-data<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are the best! TNQ ♥

Answer (score 0):

The empty space is because of the fact that there still exists the content of the previous tab(s) in the browsers 3d space (of sorts) that cause the rest to move down accordingly. You will need to effectively make them invisible both visually as well as in the browsers 3d space i.e. set their display property to `display:none`. But this causes yet another problem , the problem being that the `display:none` is not affected by any transition timings/delays so its almost instantaneous and your other transitions will be useless.

So to sum up you have three options

1. Find some way to implement javascript/jQuery code.
2. You'll just have to live with it.
3. Dabble around with the `float` and `position` properties

Comment: I choose the third item. How should I do this?

Comment: A simple way is to understand the mechanism of something closer i.e. Image sliders or sliders in general , here is a tutorial on a purely CSS one, just adapt it according to your needs . Link : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/